# Swift language: How do I implement a dictionary of array values, and assign (ie. append) new values to the array?

Tags: swift

Language: Swift

I declared a dictionary whose value is an array, like this:

```
var unloadedImagesRows = [String:[Int]]()

private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    print("addToUnloadedImagesRow 0: row: \(row)")
    var unloadedRows = imagesRowForLocation(forLocation)
    unloadedRows!.append(row)
}

private func imagesRowForLocation(location:String!) -> [Int]! {
    var unloadedRows = unloadedImagesRows[location];
    if unloadedRows == nil {
        unloadedRows = [Int]()
        unloadedImagesRows[location] = unloadedRows
    }
    return unloadedRows
} 

private func someMethod() {
    addToUnloadedImagesRow(rowIndex, forLocation: event.iconImg)
    ...
}
```

The "unloadedRows!.append(row)" works and I saw in my debugger works as I saw the count increased to 1.

However, the next time I retrieve the value as in line "var unloadedRows = unloadedImagesRows[location]", I get a result of an array containing 0 values.

How do I implement a dictionary of array values, and assign (ie. append) new values to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unloadedRows = imagesRowForLocation(forLocation)
unloadedRows!.append(row)
unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = unloadedRows!
```

You retrieve the array by value, i.e. another instance of the array stored inside the dictionary gets created. Therefore you should set it back into the dictionary after appending a value

Comment: You said the array is retrieved by value, how to retrieve it as a reference instead?

Comment: Arrays are value types in swift, they aren't passed around by reference. If you want reference semantics,  use NSArray or create a class that wraps your array